# Generated sigma algebra and its countable subcollection

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\scr{C}$ be a collection of subsets. Prove that if $A \in \sigma(\scr{C})$ (sigma algebra generated by $\scr{C}$), then there exists a countable subcollection $\scr{C}_A$ of $\scr{C}$ such that $A \in \sigma(\scr{C}_A)$

If $\scr{C}$ is finite, I think the result is immediate. Assume $\scr{C}$ is infinite. Then I know that $\sigma(\scr{C})$ is uncountable (infinite sigma algebra is always uncountable). That all I know. I think that it is impossible to have a clear form of a set belonging to a given infinite sigma algebra. So it is really no clue how to do it. I try contradiction, but no further development for the case when $\scr{C}$ is uncountable.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate Q because I answered it before. Let $B_0(C)$ be the Boolean algebra generated by $ C.$ For $a\in \omega_1$ let  $B(a+1)$ be the Boolean algebra generated by unions of countable subsets of $ B_a.$  For $ 0<a=\cup a \leq \omega_1$ let  $B_a=\cup_{d<a}B_d.$ Then $ \sigma (C)=B_{\omega_1}.$ Use  transfinite induction  for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $\mathcal{A} = \cup \{\sigma(\mathcal{B}): \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{C} \text{ at most countable }\}$.

Check that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Clearly $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ and the reverse also holds, as $\mathcal{A}$ is *a* $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$, and $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the minimal one. So we have equality and you're done.

Some details are left to you..

Comment: Thank you very much. If I need further assistance, I will ask later.

Comment: @user254665 Now, I finish showing $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but I do not see the reason why $\scr{C}$ must be contained in $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: @user254665 Okay, I think I kind of noticing the reason. Let $A \in \scr{C}$. Then $A \in \sigma(\{A\}) \subseteq \scr{A}$. So $\scr{C} \subseteq \mathscr{A.}$

Comment: Indeed, that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the collection of sets $A$ such that $A \in \sigma(\scr{C}')$ for some countable subcollection $\scr{C}'$ of $\scr{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\scr{C}$. Hence, the two coincide, and your desired result follows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is true. Let $A$ be an uncountable set, and take ${\scr C} = \{\{a\}\mid a\in A\}$. Then $\scr C$ is uncountable and you cannot remove any of its elements if you want to be able to get $A$ back.